# How does a thenable object get rejected in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promise

I know that a `thenable` has the `then` method, but how does `Promise` know the state of the thenable objected has moved to rejected?

Example:
Here, $.ajax is a thenable and can be ducktyped as a Promise if you do this:

`Promise.resolve($.ajax({ url: '/test' }))`

But how does the promise that this expression returns handle the `catch` case?

Comment: Are there two questions ? 1)  _"but how does Promise know the state of the thenable objected has moved to rejected?"_ , 2)  _"how does the promise that this expression returns handle the catch case?"_ ?

Comment: Yes, there are.  Is that okay?  They are closely related.

Comment: Yes, ok from vantage , here. Only asked for clarification as to actual Question, or Questions presented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Promises/A+ `then` method](https://promisesaplus.com/) does take **two callbacks** - one for the fulfilment and one for the rejection case. You would [not use the `.then(…).catch(…)` pattern but `.then(…, …)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) - the second callback is the "catch case" (notice that `.catch(…)` is nothing but `.then(null, …)`).

This is how thenables are assimilated - when the second callback gets called, they reject the promise with the error. Example:

```
var rejectingPromise = Promise.resolve({
    then: function(onSuccess, onError) {
        onError(new Error);
    }
});
```

Comment: So basically a thenable object cannot have two separate then and catch functions?

Comment: Ok, I tried a bit on the playground and now I understand how thenable works!

Comment: @LppEdd A thenable can have a `.catch` method, but it will be ignored for promise assimilation purposes - only `.then` is called.