# Why does my "thenable" function time out?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, cancellation

I've been messing with the idea of canceling a promise is a transparent way using a higher order function. And I came up with this:

```js
export const fnGetter = state => fn => (...args) => {
  if (!state.canceled) return fn(...args)
  return Promise.resolve()
}

export const cancelable = (promise, state = {}) => {
  const getFn = fnGetter(state)

  return {
    then: fn => cancelable(promise.then(getFn(fn)), state),
    catch: fn => cancelable(promise.catch(getFn(fn)), state),
    cancel: () => {
      state.canceled = true
    }
  }
}

export const withCancel = promiseReturningFn => (...args) =>
  cancelable(promiseReturningFn(...args))
```

And here are some unit tests where I'm verifying the behavior I want.

```js
const delay = withCancel(ms => new Promise(run => setTimeout(run, ms)))

test('works like normal promise when not canceled', async () => {
  const first = jest.fn()
  const second = jest.fn()

  await delay(1000).then(first).then(second)

  expect(first).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  expect(second).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})

test('when ignored, does not call callbacks', async () => {
  const first = jest.fn()
  const second = jest.fn()

  const promise = delay(1000).then(first).then(second)
  promise.cancel()

  await promise

  expect(first).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  expect(second).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

I can't figure out why the first test passes, but calling `.cancel()` in the second unit test makes it time out.

### Edit

I *think* it has something to do with the way that `await` handles the `then` method under the hood. I just need help at this point. I'd like it to be compatible with async await. Here's a passing version that doesn't rely on `await`.

```js
test('when ignored, does not call callbacks', async () => {
  const first = jest.fn()
  const second = jest.fn()

  const promise = delay(1000).then(first).then(second)
  promise.cancel()

  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(first).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(second).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  }, 2000)
})
```

Comment: If you have not already done so, I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30235261/3478010).

Comment: I hadn’t read this. Gives me some ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that [`then` should take two parameters to deal with rejections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33331700/1048572).

As for why it times out: you are using `await promise`, but `await` does use `then`, and your `promise` is cancelled so it never calls its callbacks. A cancelled promise should call the `onreject` callback, and your `fnGetter` should then ignore that cancellation error only for those callbacks that were actually expecting your cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what’s happening. From reading, it looks like `await` just takes subsequent code, wraps it into a function, and then passes that function into the `then` method of whatever is being awaited. If that’s the case, then my code is working and the `expect` statements never run because my promise (the one being awaited) is canceled. That’s why running the test with `setTimeout` works.

Here’s a basic example of the functionality I’m referring to.

```js
const func = async () => {
  await { then: () => console.log("test") }
  console.log("after")
}
```

The above code prints `"test"` and never prints `"after"` because `console.log("after")` gets wrapped in a function and passed to the object’s `then` method, which never calls it.